# For Loop in Django template for nested dictionaries

Tags: python, django, jinja2

I have a model with the following fields:

- name
- tag
- due_date

I want to be able to present this data as follows in my template:

> - tag1:
>   -- Name1
>   -- Name2
> - tag2:
>   -- Name3
>   -- Name4, etc.

In order to do this, in my `views.py` function, I am first making a list of all the values within `tag`, and then using this list to put together a dictionary that groups all the instances as per the individual values in the list.

For example, if this were a to-do app, the list would be tags such as `['home', 'office', 'hobby'...]` and the final dictionary would look like:

```
{'home': <QuerySet [<Task: Buy Milk>, <Task: Buy Food>]>, 'hobby': <QuerySet [<Task: Play guitar>, <Task: Read books>]>, 'office': <QuerySet [<Task: Send email>, <Task: Schedule Meeting>]>}
```

Once I have this dictionary of dictionaries, I pass it on to template as context.

```
def bytag(request):
    value_list = Task.objects.values_list('tag', flat=True).distinct()
    group_by_value = {}
    for value in value_list:
        group_by_value[value] = Task.objects.filter(tag=value)
    context = {'gbv': group_by_value}

    return render(request,'tasks/bytag.html', context)
```

I have tried out these queries in the shell, and they work fine. So in the template, I am trying the following to loop over the data:

```
{% block content %}

{% for item in gbv %}
{{ item }}

{% for stuff in gbv[item] %}
{{stuff.name}}

{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}

{% endblock content %}
```

While the first for-loop works, Django doesn't seem to allow me to access individual elements in the second dictionary by specifying a key thus: `gbv[item]` and I get a

`Template syntax error: Could not parse the remainder: '[item]' from 'gbv[item]'`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.items` to iterate on a dictionary.

```
{% for key, value in gbv.items %}
     {% for key2, value2 in value.items %}
           {{key2}}, {{value2}}
     {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I have tried .items. But it doesn't seem to throw up any value at all. if I insert a {{value}} after the first line, I get the following:  <QuerySet [<Task: Buy Milk>, <Task: New>, <Task: Buy PS5>]> Buy Milk New Buy PS5 <QuerySet [<Task: Buy drugs>, <Task: Paint house>, <Task: Buy Medicines>]> Buy drugs Paint house Buy Medicines <QuerySet [<Task: Send docs>, <Task: Schedule Meeting>]> Send docs Schedule Meeting

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked:

```
{% for key, values in gbv.items %}
    <h3>{{key}}</h3>
 
    {% for value in values %}
        {{value.name}}
        
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

The two errors:

1. I had to add .items as pointed out by @Mayank Gupta
2. The above actually returns a list and not a dictionary. Hence, 'key, value' was throwing up an error. I only figured this out after printing out the output of the first loop (guess I should have done that earlier - lesson learnt!)